# Is there a correspondence between contextual semantics and the type of language?

Tags: linguistic-typology, comparative-linguistics

Most of the isolating languages I am familiar with have context-bound semantics either in division into parts of speech (e.g. Chinese) or word meaning (Yoruba), or both (Chinese, again). E.g., in Chinese, the meaning of 来 in 来世 'future life' or in 来来! 'come on, move!' is different, the former having an approximate meaning of adjective, the latter roughly corresponding to an imperative form. Or the actual meaning of Yoruba ní 'on, at, in' and sí ‘onto, towards’ are to be defined by context.

Can anyone provide more examples from other isolating languages to shed some more light on this theory?

Comment: What is "context-bound semantics"?

Comment: The semantics where a meaning or a type of a part of speech is to be defined by context (like in Chinese and Yoruba). E.g. it is impossible to decide whether 来 means 'future' (adj.) or 'move!' without a context.

Comment: What makes contextual semantics differ from homonymy?

Comment: Or polysemy, for that matter?

Comment: The difference is that e.g. Chinese word lai1 has several possible meaninings, all of them dealing with a notion of 'move', there is no other 'lai1' related to, say, a notion of 'cabbage' or 'stork'.

Comment: so... zero-derivation?

Comment: What about zero-derivation? It's morphology, it's interesting, and it differs from contextual semantics (imagine a language with distinction between parts of speech, but with no derivative forms or conjugations/declensions).